# SQL generate unique ID from rolling ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to find an answer to this for the better part of a day with no luck.

I have a SQL table with measurement data for samples and I need a way to assign a unique ID to each sample. Right now each sample has an ID number that rolls over frequently. What I need is a unique ID for each sample. Below is a table with a simplified dataset, as well as an example of a possible UID that would do what I need.

```
 | Row | Time  | Meas# | Sample# | UID (Desired) |
 | 1   | 09:00 |   1   |    1    |       1       |
 | 2   | 09:01 |   2   |    1    |       1       |
 | 3   | 09:02 |   3   |    1    |       1       |
 | 4   | 09:07 |   1   |    2    |       2       |
 | 5   | 09:08 |   2   |    2    |       2       |
 | 6   | 09:09 |   3   |    2    |       2       |
 | 7   | 09:24 |   1   |    3    |       3       |
 | 8   | 09:25 |   2   |    3    |       3       |
 | 9   | 09:25 |   3   |    3    |       3       |
 | 10  | 09:47 |   1   |    1    |       4       |
 | 11  | 09:47 |   2   |    1    |       4       |
 | 12  | 09:49 |   3   |    1    |       4       |
```

My problem is that rows 10-12 have the same Sample# as rows 1-3.  I need a way to uniquely identify and group each sample. Having the row number or time of the first measurement on the sample would be good.

One other complication is that the measurement number doesn't always start with 1. It's based on measurement locations, and sometimes it skips location 1 and only has locations 2 and 3.

Comment: So, what is your expected output here exactly?

Comment: If you simply need an arbitrary identifier for each row, why not use an auto-incrementing primary key? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Since you are not showing the code used to produce this data, it is hard to tell you where the problem is and how to fix it. My advice is to normalize the data. I.e, you should have one `sample` table and one `measurement` table in a 1-to-many relation. Like this you would always have one sample row per sample and could use an identity column as sample #.

Comment: Why doesn't `row` do what you want?  What is a "sample"?

Comment: @DanFarrell The table already has an auto-incrementing key in the Row column of the sample data.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes What I showed here is simplified example that I created to illustrate the type of issue. My actual data is coming from a much larger and more complex data collection system, so I don't have an option to change the original table structure.

Comment: could you use newid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to speculate that you want a unique number assigned to each sample, where now you have repeats.

If so, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_sample = sample then 0 else 1 end) over (order by row) as new_sample_number
from (select t.*,
             lag(sample) over (order by row) as prev_sample
      from t
     ) t;
```